# Use Linq and lambda to flatten a list

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda, extension-methods

I have a class.

```
public class MedicalRequest
{
    private int id
    private IList<MedicalDays> Days 
    private string MedicalUser
    ...
}
```

and another

```
public class MedicalDays
{
    private int id;
    private DateTime? day
    private MedicalRequest request
    ...
}
```

I have the MedicalUser so I'm able to select an

```
IList<MedicalRequest> reqList = dao.FindAll(example);
```

What I would love to be able to do at this point is flatten out the Lists of MedicalDays and return the DateTime day.

Something like

```
IList<DateTime> dateList = reqList.SelectMany(i => i.MedicalDays.day);
```

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're nearly there:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime?> dateList = reqList.SelectMany(i => i.MedicalDays)
                                         .Select(m => m.day);
```

Or:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime?> dateList = reqList.SelectMany(i => i.MedicalDays,
                                                     (i, m) => m.day);
```

- If you need an `IList<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` you can call `ToList()` on the result
- If you need to work with `DateTime` instead of `DateTime?` you can filter out null days like this:

  ```
  IEnumerable<DateTime?> dateList = reqList.SelectMany(i => i.MedicalDays)
                                           .Select(m => m.day)
                                           .Where(x => x.HasValue)
                                           .Select(x => x.Value);
  ```

Comment: Thank you Jon, very helpful as always.

Answer (score 5):

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dateList = reqList.SelectMany(i => i.MedicalDays)
                                        .Select(i => i.day);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Ben.